# PHP exec ImageMagick - magick convert not working ubuntu linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick, exec

I'm using ubuntu and have installed ImageMagick

```
identify -version
```

gives:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

I tried:

```
exec('magick img.jpg ( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 ) ( -clone 0 -color-threshold "gray(251)-gray(254)" ) -compose over -composite -quality 80% result.jpg', $output, $return_var);
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($output) , '</pre>';
```

also `convert` and `magick convert` instead of `magick`

then according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127260/imagemagick-convert-not-allowed) answer I opened `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

and changed `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` to `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />`

but still doesn't work and `$output` always returns empty array

PS: I don't want to use the PHP extension, already did and it has some flaws

Comment: "magick" is for Imagemagick 7. You need to use "convert" for imagemagick 6.  In Unix, you need to escape your parentheses with "\". If on a shared server, you will not be able to change the policy.xml file. The server hosting providers will need to do that. -color-threshold is only available in Imagemagick 7. You are using Imagemagick 6.

Comment: I have a vServer with root access. I just tried to do just exec('magick img.jpg result.jpg', $output, $return_var); and it worked, so I guess the command need to be different than on windows server. "In Unix, you need to escape your parentheses with "\"" what does this mean? Can you show example?

Comment: You claim that your Imagemagick version is Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23. So "magick" should not work. It is only for Imagemagick 7. Perhaps you have multiple versions of Imagemagick on your system.  In Unix, in place of "(" and ")". You need "\(" and "\)".  Windows syntax has some differences from Unix syntax.  Escaping parentheses is one of those differences.

Comment: Yes my bad I mean convert. in place of "(" and ")". You need "(" and ")" you mean "/(" and "/)"? I just tried, still doesn't work. Can you check for errors please: convert img.jpg /( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 /) /( -clone 0 -color-threshold "gray/(251/)-gray/(254/)" /) -compose over -composite -quality 80% result.jpg

Comment: -color-threshold only works for Imagemagick 7.

Comment: Backslash, not forward slash. For Imagemagick 7, `magick img.jpg \( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 -color-threshold "gray(251)-gray(254)" \) -compose over -composite -quality 80% result.jpg`

Comment: Thanks it works! Make an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Oh and yeah I installed ImageMagick 7.1 to see if this will solve the problem, good thing that I did

Comment: So did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do some testing in Imagemagick with PHP to see what your versions are. Please provide any messages that come back for each.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("type -a convert");  
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

```
<?php
exec("magick -version",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

Does this work?

```
<?php
exec('magick img.jpg \( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \) \( -clone 0 -color-threshold "gray(251)-gray(254)" \) -compose over -composite -quality 80% result.jpg 2>&1',$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

What messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Convert writes its output to disk (`result.jpg`). The output argument of `exec()` if for any output to stdout. If you want the image data in`$output` specify an output file of `-`.

To quote the man page:

> By default, the image format of 'file' is determined by its magic number. To specify a particular image format, precede the filename with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps). Specify 'file' as '-' for standard input or output.

Comment: Can you show example? I used this command on my previous server with Windows Server 2016 on it and it worked, the only difference is I pointed directly to the .exe of ImageMagick there which was in the website folder

Comment: The question is, do you really want the binary output of the converted image in `$output` instead of a file?

Comment: It suppose to generate result.jpg as seen in the end of the code

Comment: So, as expected nothing goes to `$output` since the data goes to `result.jpg`. So what is the problem?

Comment: result.jpg is not generated, I said that $outpout is empty to point out that I don't get any messages, neither error nor success

Comment: Possibly error message would go to `stderr`, so would not go to `$output`. YOu can try to add a 2>&1 to the command to route `stderr` to `stdout`. Real code would use `proc_open` instead of `exec` (which is always dangerous), and in `proc_open` you can manage both output streams.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with 2>&1, now $output is always showing!